# Push после локального Merge

Tags: git, git-merge, push

Локально влил изменения из одной ветки в другую (git merge) Теперь не пойму как измененную ветку выгрузить на сервер через git push.

Comment: история ветки значения не должна играть. Как вы до этого push делали так и продолжайте.

Comment: Если нет конфликтов, то `git push`. Если конфликты есть, правим их, потом `git commit`, `git push`